# HDD not recognized after reconnecting

Tags: hard-drive

My hard drive works fine when connected to a notebook through an adapter, but when I put it back in the notebook it came out of, it is not recognized.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Update:

It started as a recovery virus so I took out the drive to get the data off of it then put it back in to reinstall XP pro, it was time for a reinstall anyway. 
It came up hal.ddl was missing,  when I put the OS disk in, it didn't find the drive.
I am formatting the drive now to see if that will help.

hp pav dv5000

Comment: Is the flat cable from the drive to the mainboard buckled?

Comment: Exact Model of notebook? Exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard without knowing a little more, but, I would say:

If the computer is not booting or detecting the hard drive at all, the storage controller on the motherboard may be damaged (confirm if the laptop can not detect any other drive either).

Next, if your hard drive is being detected by the laptop, but, it is just coming up with errors, you may want to try a startup repair or use your vendor specific repair disk.

If these don't help, I really need more information to help you further.

Comment: I am trying to install Xp Pro. It loads the files then says no hard drive has bee detected.